# Missing template error on when background processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using background processing with the **resque** gem and **bioruby**, and the processing is correctly functioning. I am however getting a "missing template" error. It seems the action is trying to load a template.

```
Missing template cosmics/start_batch, application/start_batch with {:locale=>[:en],
:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

I do not want a template loaded: the background process retrieves data from an external source and then updates a database table (this is all working).

The code is triggered by a button:

```
<%= link_to 'Process', start_batch_path, :class =>"btn btn-primary" %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
match '/cosmics/start_batch', :to => 'cosmics#start_batch', :as => 'start_batch'
resources :batches do
  resources :batch_details
end
```

cosmics_controller.rb

```
def start_batch
  @batch = Batch.create!(:status => 'created',:status_timestamp => Time.now)
  @cosmics = Cosmic.find(:all, :conditions => {:selected => true}).each do |cosmic|
    @batch_detail = BatchDetail.create!(:batch_id => @batch.id, :cosmic_mut_id => cosmic.cosmic_mut_id)
    @batch_detail.save
    cosmic.selected = false
    cosmic.save
  end
  Resque.enqueue(UcscQuery,@batch.id)
end
```

workers/ucsc_query.rb (Reqsue worker class)

```
class UcscQuery
  require 'bio-ucsc'
  include Bio 

@queue = :ucsc_queue

def self.perform(batch_id)
  Ucsc::Hg19.connect
  @batch_detail = BatchDetail.find(:all, :conditions => {:batch_id => batch_id}).each do |batch_detail|
    ucsc_cosmic = Ucsc::Hg19::Cosmic.find_by_name(batch_detail.cosmic_mut_id)
    if ucsc_cosmic
      batch_detail.bin = ucsc_cosmic.bin
      batch_detail.chrom = ucsc_cosmic.chrom
      batch_detail.chrom_start = ucsc_cosmic.chromStart
      batch_detail.chrom_end = ucsc_cosmic.chromEnd
      batch_detail.status = 'processed'
      batch_detail.save
    end
  end
  Batch.update(batch_id, :status => 'located')
end
end
```

How can I prevent Rails from trying to load a cosmics/start_batch template? Any refactoring tips would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no `render` nor `redirect` instruction in a controller method, Rails looks for a view with the same name of the method. To change this behavior, add `render :nothing => true` at the end of the `start_batch` method.

With this, when the user will click on the `Process` link, it will render a blank page. That's certainly not what you want. You can use `:remote => true`  option in the `link_to` so the user will stay on the current page:

```
<%= link_to 'Process', start_batch_path, {:remote => true}, {id: 'process_btn', :class => "btn btn-primary"} %>
```

Finally, use javascript to show the user that "something" happened when he clicked on the button. Example:

```
$('#process_btn').on('click', function() { alert('Batch process started'); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type:

```
render :nothing => true
```

in your action. I would also advice changing your link to remote

```
<%= link_to 'Process', start_batch_path, :class =>"btn btn-primary", :remote => true %>
```

Otherwise you'll see blank page after clicking on it.